# return statement is not executing loops but print does

Tags: python, function, while-loop, return

**here i am getting multiplication table using print statement.**

```
userNum = int(input("enter a number:"))

def multiply(n):

    comp = 10
    count = 0
    while comp > count:
        count+=1
        z = n*count
        y = "{1} * {2} = {0}".format(z,n,count)
        print(y)
     multiply(userNum)
```

here i am getting only 5 *1 = 5.it does not execute other despite using loops

```
userNum = int(input("enter a number:"))

def multiply(n):

    comp = 10
    count = 0
    while comp > count:
        count+=1
        z = n*count
        y = "{1} * {2} = {0}".format(z,n,count)
        return y
      a = multiply(userNum)
     print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment

> "so how to return loops in function without print statement?any
> solution?"

You could write a nested loop in order to loop over a list, which stores the items returned by the function. For example:

```
userNum = int(input("enter a number:"))

y_values = []

def multiply(n):
    comp = 10
    count = 0
    while comp > count:
        count+=1
        z = n*count
        y = "{1} * {2} = {0}".format(z,n,count)
        y_values.append(y)

multiply(userNum)
```

You can then loop over the list to print the items:

```
for y in y_values:
    print(y)
```

OUTPUT, as expected:

```
enter a number:5
5 * 1 = 5
5 * 2 = 10
5 * 3 = 15
5 * 4 = 20
5 * 5 = 25
5 * 6 = 30
5 * 7 = 35
5 * 8 = 40
5 * 9 = 45
5 * 10 = 50
```

Comment: this is the reason i hate programming.i can't understand properly.
is this python syntax [for n < len(y_values):]?...it didn't work.or [for n in range()]?

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: for loop..it say int obj is not iterable

Comment: Just realized I made a mistake in the code. Just edited it! Thanks for spotting it!

Comment: no output shown..i want multiplication of 5*1=5 to 5*10=50..it didn't work.

Comment: @Einsking Sorry, made a mistake with indentation just now. I just edited my answer again and it returns the output you requested. Hope this helps!

Comment: When you copy the code I provided into Python, please make sure you indented it correctly. Thanks!

Comment: can you explain when should we use return statement?is print statement only for console or can also be use in for creating program.your code work.so this is how we get loops value inside function?

Comment: Typically, we use return statements to return values from a function. However, since your function involves a loop, you cannot use the return function within the loop, as you can only return one item for each function. You should return the list of values at the end of the function. If this helps, please upvote/accept my two answers, as I would really appreicate it! :)

Comment: thanks mate.i understand how your code work.i just created account today and don't know how to upvote but i will google and upvote you

Comment: it says votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but does not change the displayed post.

Comment: If you can't upvote, you can search up how to "accept" an answer, which means you find my answer useful. You also get points for accepting an answer! Thanks! :)

Comment: it says don't thank someone if you find answer useful.LoL.

Answer (score 4):

This is because in Python, the `return` statement automatically exits the function, because a function can only return one item. Hence, in the second scenario, once `y` was returned, it exited the function, so it only printed the first item in the `while` loop.

Comment: so how to return loops in function without print statement?any solution?